# React useEffectin App.js before children component renders

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my React App.js component I execute the following code:

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAuthenticatedUser());
  }, []);
```

This code fetches the current authenticated user by session from an API and will fill the redux store. However this code seems to run after the children of App are rendered. The children components use state variables, because this function is executed after my child components are rendered it won't work. I need this function to be called once before I render my child components within App.js, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ask React to delay rendering, that's just not how React is supposed to work (unless you're using experimental features like Suspense, but you should probably learn idiomatic React first).
You normally simply tell React what to display depending on the current state/props, and React will automatically rerender as soon as something changed.

So if you have no state variable saying that the app is in a loading state, you should make one. After all, whether it is currently loading or not is intuitively part of the current "state" of the app, especially if you are on a slow connection for instance.

Comment: Alright thanks for your answer, currently i've added a 'checkedSession' variable to my redux store. If its false I render a loading spinner otherwise I just render my app. Is this a good approach? If not what should I rather do?

Comment: Yes, seems good to me!

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like a ternary that only renders those children when these variables are available, something like:

```
variables ? <Children/> : <Loading/>
```

[Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) is a great experimental feature that could help you handle this if you're willing to be an early adopter!

Comment: this would not work because I have no state or variable im receiving that tells me the function is done loading. I just need it to be dispatched before the App components starts rendered.

Comment: It seems to me that just dispatching it before the App components start rendering will create a race condition in which you never know what will happen first. You can always check if the variables are available inside your component before rendering it, trying to trigger this dispatch 'early' is not something that React supports AFAIK.